# Computed Observable Array from Observable Arrays

Tags: knockout.js

I am using Knockout to do something that I thought is simple. I am new to Knockout and JavaScript, therefore stuck. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Following is the problem at Hand.

I have three inventories of products (opening, closing, delivered) in the form of array and I want to compute the sold product inventory in the form of array. Actual data is bit complex. Here is the simplified version of my **Data**

```
var OpeningGasInventories = [{
  Id: 0,
  Volume: 0,
  TimeStamp: "0001-01-01T05:00:00Z",
  GasInventoryType: "Opening",
  GasProductId: 1, 
  ShiftId: 1
}, {
 Id: 0,
  Volume: 0,
  TimeStamp: "0001-01-01T05:00:00Z",
  GasInventoryType: "Opening",
  GasProductId: 2, 
  ShiftId: 1
}];

var ClosingGasInventories = [{
  Id: 0,
  Volume: 0,
  TimeStamp: "0001-01-01T05:00:00Z",
  GasInventoryType: "Opening",
  GasProductId: 1, 
  ShiftId: 1
}, {
 Id: 0,
  Volume: 0,
  TimeStamp: "0001-01-01T05:00:00Z",
  GasInventoryType: "Opening",
  GasProductId: 2, 
  ShiftId: 1
  }];


var DeliveredGasInventories = [{
  Id: 0,
  Volume: 0,
  TimeStamp: "0001-01-01T05:00:00Z",
  GasInventoryType: "Opening",
  GasProductId: 1, 
  ShiftId: 1
}, {
 Id: 0,
  Volume: 0,
  TimeStamp: "0001-01-01T05:00:00Z",
  GasInventoryType: "Opening",
  GasProductId: 2, 
  ShiftId: 1
  }];

 var SoldGasInventories = [{
  Id: 0,
  Volume: 0,
  TimeStamp: "0001-01-01T05:00:00Z",
  GasInventoryType: "Opening",
  GasProductId: 1, 
  ShiftId: 1
}, {
 Id: 0,
  Volume: 0,
  TimeStamp: "0001-01-01T05:00:00Z",
  GasInventoryType: "Opening",
  GasProductId: 2, 
  ShiftId: 1
  }];

 var  GasProductSales= [{
  Id: 1,
  CashPrice: 1.919,
  CreditPrice: 0,
  VolumeCashSale: 0,
  VolumeCreditSale: 0,
  AmountCashSale: 0,
  AmountCreditSale: 0,
  GasProductId: 1,
  GasProductName: "Regular",
  ShiftId: 1
}, {
  Id: 2,
  CashPrice: 2.379,
  CreditPrice: 0,
  VolumeCashSale: 0,
  VolumeCreditSale: 0,
  AmountCashSale: 0,
  AmountCreditSale: 0,
  GasProductId: 2,
  GasProductName: "Premium",
  ShiftId: 1
}];
```

Following is my Knokcout code to compute Totals of each inventory and compute the sold inventory array

```
 var AppViewModel = function() {
 var self = this;

   self.OpeningGasInventories = ko.mapping.fromJS(OpeningGasInventories);
   self.ClosingGasInventories = ko.mapping.fromJS(ClosingGasInventories);
   self.DeliveredGasInventories =    ko.mapping.fromJS(DeliveredGasInventories);
  self.SoldGasInventories = ko.mapping.fromJS(SoldGasInventories);
  self.GasProductSales = ko.mapping.fromJS(GasProductSales);


 self.TotalOpeningGasInventory = ko.computed(function() {

        // Now calculate the sum of all Open Gas inventories
        var total = 0;
        self.OpeningGasInventories()
            .forEach(function(item, index) {
                total += +item.Volume() || 0;
            });

        return total.toFixed(0);
    });

    //Compute total of closing gas inventory
    self.TotalClosingGasInventory = ko.computed(function() {

        // Now calculate the sum of all Open Gas inventories
        var total = 0;
        self.ClosingGasInventories()
            .forEach(function(item, index) {
                total += +item.Volume() || 0;
            });

        return total.toFixed(0);
    });


    //Compute total of Delivered gas inventory
    self.TotalDeliveredGasInventory = ko.computed(function() {            
        var total = 0;
        self.DeliveredGasInventories()
            .forEach(function(item, index) {
                total += +item.Volume() || 0;
            });

        return total.toFixed(0);
    });

    //Compute total of Sold gas inventory
    self.TotalSoldGasInventory = ko.computed(function() {            
        var total = 0;           
        self.SoldGasInventories()
            .forEach(function(item, index) {
                console.info("Volume is " + item.Volume());
                total += +item.Volume() || 0;
            });           
        return total.toFixed(0);
    });

   self.SoldGasInventories = ko.computed(function() {            
        //we know all the four arrays are in same order and of same length 

        for (var i = 0; i < self.SoldGasInventories().length; i++) {                          

            self.SoldGasInventories()[i]
                .Volume = parseFloat(self.OpeningGasInventories()[i].Volume()) +
                parseFloat(self.DeliveredGasInventories()[i].Volume()) -
                parseFloat(self.ClosingGasInventories()[i].Volume());          

        }        

        return self.SoldGasInventories();
    });
 };
```

Issue: If I comment the last computed function  ***self.SoldGasInventories*** then all the arrays totals are being computed fine.This last function suppose to computed the SoldGasInvetories array but it is not working as I would expect. Once I uncomment this function then the self.TotalSoldGasInventory does not get called.
I have created a [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/8nj31seh/44/) Please check and help me resolve my issue. Thanks a million..

Comment: That's because in `SoldGasInventories()` you're not *updating* the observable but instead *replacing* it with the value. Try `.Volume(...)` instead of `.Volume = ...`. See https://jsfiddle.net/8nj31seh/45/ (not sure it properly calculates values after the change though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last computed doesn't return a computed value, but rather updates other observables.

```
self.UpdateSoldGasInventoriesVolumes = ko.computed(function() {
    //we know all the four arrays are in same order and of same length
    for (var i = 0; i < self.SoldGasInventories().length; i++) {
        self.SoldGasInventories()[i].Volume(
            parseFloat(self.OpeningGasInventories()[i].Volume()) +
            parseFloat(self.DeliveredGasInventories()[i].Volume()) -
            parseFloat(self.ClosingGasInventories()[i].Volume())
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: @haim770 thanks a lot. That resolved the problem. Thanks a million

Comment: Thanks to you also. I couldn't put your name in previous comment.

Comment: I added one additional functionality that is not working as I want. I want to show the StoreProducts available for sale in tabular form and allow user to provide an input for number of units sold for each item. It should update the "TotalAmount" (price*units sold) and also provide totalamount of all products sold. Here is [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/8nj31seh/54/). Thanks a lot.

Comment: A `ko.computed` that is used to set other values should not return a new value. You should not be replacing `SoldGasInventories`, but use another name like I did above. (You actually don't even need to give it a name.) But the fix is to use the `value` binding for an `<input>`. https://jsfiddle.net/8nj31seh/55/

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining that. I got it. One question. In the current functionality of let's stay store section. When I enter a value in the input box and go out of focus from that input box that is when the computed function runs and compute the values. What do I need to do if I want it to run it as soon as I enter a value (without going out of the input box). I hope I had explained. Thanks a lot buddy.

Comment: Use `textInput` binding instead of `value`.